# error: storage size of 'name' isn't known

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error when compiling. Can someone tell me why this happens?
I have these structs declared in board.c:

```
struct point {
  short int rank;
  short int file;
};

struct pieces {
  Point pawns[8];
  Point Knights[2];
  Point BBishop;
  Point WBishop;
  Point Rooks[2];
  Point Queen;
  Point King;
};
```

I also have these typedefs in board.h:

```
typedef struct point Point;
typedef struct pieces Pieces;
```

In the main source file (chess.c), I have the declaration:

```
Pieces White;
```

When i compile it says:

```
chess.c: In function 'main':
chess.c:19:10: error: storage size of 'White'isn't known
```

I tried moving the struct over to board.h, which works just fine. Why wouldn't it work when i have the struct in board.c though?

gcc compiler

Comment: I just finished a project 1 week ago, which involved lists and their managment. I had the structure declared in a .c source file and it worked nicely.

Comment: The order in which declarations appear is important in C. It's generally a good idea to combine the structure definition and the typedef in the same place in a .h file so they will always refer to the same thing and it doesn't matter when you include the .h.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compiling `chess.c`, it needs to know what the `Pieces` typedef expands to in order to process a variable declared with that type.

Pointer types can be processed without knowing the full definition of the type it points to, but object types need to know the full definition, because they allocate space for the variable. And to know how much space is needed, the compiler needs to know what the structure members are.

When the compiler is processing `chess.c`, it only has the information in that source file and any files that it includes. Unless you have `#include "board.c"` somewhere, the structure definition isn't available while compiling `chess.c`. It's generally wrong to use `#include` with `.c` files, it should normally only be used with `.h` files. This is why structure definitions and their corresponding typedefs are normally put in the `.h` file.

Comment: I understand what the compiler needs with this answer.  I don't think you have answered the OP's question though "Why wouldn't it work when i have the struct in board.c though?"

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Added another paragraph explaining this.

Comment: I see. So if for example the statement in board.h was    "typedef struct pieces *Pieces", it would work because any variable of type Pieces would be a pointer?